# iframe内にログインの必要なページを表示すると、ログインができないのですが、一般的に起こる現象でしょうか？対処法はありますか？

Tags: html

iframe内にログインの必要なページを表示すると、ログインができないのですが、
これは、一般的に起こる現象でしょうか？

ログインできるようにする方法はありますか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: iframe内のドキュメントと親のドキュメントは同一オリジンですか?

Comment: 同じサイト内のページです。ただ、今サンプルで親のページを作っている段階なので、ローカルにあるhtml内にiframeを作って、別ドメインのページを見ている感じです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

親ページと`iframe`内に表示しているページのドメインが異なる場合、[サードパーティクッキー](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#third-party_cookies)送信を抑止するような設定がWebブラウザに対して行われているとそのような挙動になります。

これが原因の場合は、Webブラウザの設定を変更し、サードパーティクッキーブロックを解除すれば想定した挙動になります。

設定方法:

- [Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=ja#zippy=%2Ccookie-%E3%82%92%E8%A8%B1%E5%8F%AF%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AF%E3%83%96%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)
- [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/ja/kb/disable-third-party-cookies)
- [Safari](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/guide/safari/sfri40732/mac)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！ということは、これが原因の場合は、こういうページを公開すると、閲覧者が各々でブラウザでこの設定をしない限り、ログインできないということになりますよね？

Comment: 現時点ではその通りになります。現在は状況が推移している真っ最中で、プライバシー保護を目的としてブラウザのデフォルト設定がサードパーティブロックになりつつありますが、まだ今回質問されているような機能の代替が確立していません。本機能の代替としては [WebID](https://github.com/WICG/WebID)(※ [仮称](https://github.com/WICG/WebID/issues/41)) が検討されているようです。

Comment: いろいろご教示いただきありがとうございます！参考にさせていただきます。